# AMD and Nvidia: which provide longer driver update/support for Graphic Card?

Tags: graphics-card

While I already know about the difference between their price,
energy efficiency, and performance,

I am interested in which company will provide a longer driver support/update for their graphic card.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graphics card information. We have decided that graphics cards and their related aspects are not gaming specific utilities.

Comment: Then why is there a graphics card tag? He literally used a tag that leads to many questions...

Comment: @Probst - Just a guess, since I'm basically clueless here, maybe it's meant to be more of an indicator on questions where a PC player is having (potential) graphics related issues? Either way, this is not directly gaming related and borders on hardware recommendation (I know it is not, but it's clearly suggestive as such). I have also voted to close.

Comment: I think it is relevant, it is a question about how long the card is supported (for use in games) and I think that seeing this information can help people make their own hardware selection.

Comment: @Frank Instead of closing it this should be moved to superuser I believe.

Comment: @Zerjack Do Superuser answer hardware recommendations now?

Comment: @Studoku It's not a hardware recommendation, it's a question about existing hardware.

Comment: While it is a question about things that exist, it is also a question about which is better based on a set of metrics (in this case, the length of updates and support). It's very likely to be off topic on SU, as it reads like "help me choose a thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia tends to support their GPUs for an extra year or two longer than AMD but it partially depends on their development cycles and timings of their new GPU releases for exactly how long they support old GPUs. Both companies typically support their products for at least 5 years. Note that this is about 5 years from the chipset in the card being introduced, a rebranded card will likely have a shorter support cycle because the "about 5 years" starts with the original card.

Answer (score 1):

I have an old GeForce FX 5500 (on my shelf), which I'm pretty sure I bought in 2004.  According to nVidia's driver download/search page, the last updated driver for it is dated June of 2008:

[image]

This would suggest that Probst's indication of about 5 years is correct.

On the other hand, [AMD announced a few months ago](http://betanews.com/2015/11/24/amd-kills-gpu/) that they would be discontinuing support for several graphics cards...

> "AMD Radeon HD 8000 Series (HD 8400 and below), Radeon HD 7000 Series (HD 7600 and below), Radeon HD 6000 Series, and Radeon HD 5000 Series Graphics products have reached peak performance optimization as of November 24th, 2015. These products have been moved to a legacy support model and no additional driver releases are planned. This change enables us to dedicate valuable engineering resources to developing new features and enhancements for graphics products based on the GCN Architecture", says Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."

It looks like the [Radeon HD 8000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_8000_series)'s came out in 2013, so that suggests that you may have less than 3 years of driver support from AMD.

Comment: Well there is an interesting reason for that actually, see the HD 8000 series is entirely a rebrand of old GPUs. HD 8400 and bellow and HD 7600 and bellow are rebranded HD 6000 cards or possibly even HD 5000 series cards. So I suppose more accurately it's not about 5 years since the card was released but about 5 years since the chipset the card is based on was first released, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @Probst Good point.  So the short timespan of support for the Radeon HD 8000's is probably atypical then.

Comment: Yes, the entire HD 8000 series is pretty atypical, they did not release any new chipsets for it at all and as far as I know you can not actually buy an HD 8000 series card they only came with prebuilt computers. I heard that they only did it because companies like Dell and Lenovo were complaining that they wanted to have something that sounds newer but I'm not sure if that's true or not...